# RegEx - Not ending with certain suffixes

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate a form input with an email address. I already have a RegEx for checking that it ends with certain suffixes (`^.+@((gmail\.com)|(hotmail\.fr))$`). Now, I would like to validate the opposite.

How can I match an email address that does **not** end with certain suffixes with a RegEx?

Edit: I'm using [jQuery validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) with unobtrusive validation, e.g.:

```
<input id="auth_email" name="auth_email" type="email" 
       data-rule-pattern="^.+@((gmail\.com)|(hotmail\.fr))$"
       data-msg-pattern="The email address must not end with '@gmail.com' or '@hotmail.fr'"
       class="form-control" required  data-lpignore="true">
```

I would really prefer a pure RegEx solution.

Comment: Yon use negative lookahead `^(?!.+\.(?:gmail|example)\.com$).+`

Comment: `if (!/.../.test(input))`

Comment: Why do you need the negative case?  Is there some reason why a whitelist is less workable than a blacklist?

Comment: You just need to negate the result using `!` or `===false`

Comment: @melpomene: I'm using unobtrusive validation with jQuery validate. See edit for more info.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to make it work thanks to @anubhava' comment.